# How to add range for DateTime validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, blazor-server-side

I have a simple input model for my blazor server side component. I want to use the build in validation for a DateTime property.

```
[Required]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

How can I only accept DateTime values >= DateTime.Now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to create a custom validation attribute. But do it well, not as shown in the answers above...

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace YourAppNamespace
{
    public class FromNowAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public FromNowAttribute() {}

        public string GetErrorMessage() => "Date must be past now";

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var date = (DateTime)value;

            if (DateTime.Compare(date, DateTime.Now) < 0) return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
            else return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
[Required]
[FromNow]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: What is the difference by inhert from ValidationAttribute instead of the Interface IValidatableObject that Roman mentioned below?

Comment: Here I've created a custom validation attribute for one, or many, properties that you decorate. With IValidatableObject you choose to add some methods (Validate, at least) to the whole model class, and you're somehow indicating that this method run each time the validation is performed. This is more indicated for complex validations where there're several properties involved, it's an overhead for your use case and it has to be applied to every model class... You can apply the above attribute in as many properties of as many classes you want. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom range attribute.

```
public class CustomDateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
  public CustomDateAttribute()
    : base(typeof(DateTime),. 
            DateTime.NowToShortDateString(),
            DateTime.MaxValue.ToShortDateString()) 
  { } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `IValidatableObject` interface:

```
public class MyClass: IValidatableObject 
{
    // other properties
 
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (this.Date < DateTime.Now)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Date is invalid/out of range");
        }

        // other validation conditions
    }
}
```